# What could be the reason that i can't access to the other pages of my localhost wordpress website except the homepage?

Tags: 404-error, local-installation

I can't figure this out on google. I was getting the following error. [image]

Comment: What are your permalink settings, and what are the contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Login in to admin and update permalink from setting menu.

Comment: Thank you @bosco, jaydeep. I just changed the permalink  settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your .htaccess likely wasn't inited. You can go into your settings/permalinks and hit save and this will flush the settings for you and it should work.